# Firestore: Query documents by property of object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've a collection with contacts with a structure like:

```
name: 'XPTO Company',
emails: { 
    susan@xpto.com: { name: 'Susan', text: 'manager' },
    fred@xpto.com: { name: 'Fred', text: 'marketing' }
}
```

How do I retrieve documents with email 'susan@xpto.com'

Something like:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('contacts')
      .where(new firebase.firestore.FieldPath('emails', email), '==', true).get()
      .then(snap => {
      })
```

Comment: Does what you proposed not work?

Comment: It doesn't. Think only work for boolean values, not objects.

Comment: Can you create a sub-collection of the company for individual contacts?

Comment: @JasonBerryman I am pretty sure that you can currently not query by subcollections. They mentioned that we should restructure our data if we want to do something like this.

Comment: It depends where you need to query from. If you know that a contact belongs to a particular company, then this is easy. You are correct that you cannot query sub collections across multiple documents

Comment: Creating a sub-collection is not a solution (at least while it's not possible to query by sub-collections), because I need to find the company that has an employee with that email.

Answer (score 7):

You may add a property `id` that holds the email address to your email object. and replace '.' in email object key with '-', e.g. `susan@xpto-com`, so that your data structure looks like this:

```
name: 'XPTO Company',
emails: { 
    susan@xpto-com: { id: 'susan@xpto.com', name: 'Susan', text: 'manager' },
    fred@xpto-com: { id: 'fred@xpto.com', name: 'Fred', text: 'marketing' }
```

Then you can retrieve documents with email 'susan@xpto.com' in this way:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('contacts')
      .where('emails.susan@xpto-com.id', '==', 'susan@xpto.com').get()
      .then(snap => {
      })
```