# Firestore : Query documents by property of objects

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

To Query from `Firebase Firestore` documents by using properties of objects.

***My Data Structure :***

```
document{  
  id:"document-id",
  user: {
    name:"John",
    email:"example@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

*How to query from a collection in which I want documents having "example@gmail.com" as email address of user.*

***Note:***
This question is similar to this one : [Firestore: Query documents by property of object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49613117/9636037)
But, that question is for backend(node) and this one is for frontend(java).

Comment: The syntax is the same for all languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is to use **Dot operator** for objects to access attributes, just as we use in normal java programs.

Example:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collection_name")
        .whereEqualTo("user.email", "example@gmail.com");
```